# Piping the output of ssh sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, tty

I sometimes have a need to run commands as root on a remote server, and parse the output of the command on my local server.  The remote server does not allow root login by `ssh`, but has `sudo` configured in a way that requires a password.  A simplified example of what I need to do is

```
ssh remote sudo echo bar | tr bar foo
```

(Obviously in this simplified example, there's no good reason to need to run `echo` on a different machine to `tr`: this is just a toy example to explain what I'm trying to do.)

If I run the command above, I get an error that sudo has no way to prompt for a password:

```
richard@local:~$ ssh remote sudo echo bar | tr bar foo
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

One way I can try to fix this is by adding the `-t` option to `ssh`.  If I do that, `sudo` does wait for and accept a password, but the output of `ssh`'s pseudo-terminal goes to stdout, meaning the sudo prompt message is piped to `tr` and not displayed to the user.  If the user doesn't know `sudo` is waiting for a password, they will think the script has hung, and passing the prompt message to the pipe probably breaks further processing:

```
richard@local:~$ ssh -t remote sudo echo bar | tr bar foo
[sudo] posswood foo oichood: 
foo
```

(This admittedly silly example shows the prompt has been processed by the `tr` command the output is piped to.)

The other way I can see to try to fix this is by adding the `-S` option to `sudo`.  If I do that, `sudo` prompts on stderr for the password, so the prompt is not passed down the pipeline.  That's good, but `sudo` also accepts the password on standard input meaning it's echoed to the terminal where anyone looking over the user's shoulder can read it:

```
richard@local:~$ ssh remote sudo -S echo bar | tr bar foo
[sudo] password for richard: p8ssw0rd
foo
```

I've found inelegant ways of working around the problems with these two options, but my workarounds hit a problem if the user gets their password wrong the first time.  That in itself is a problem.  Examples of this are:

```
richard@local:~$ echo "[sudo] password for $USER:"; \
  ssh -t remote sudo echo bar | tail +2 | tr bar foo

richard@local:~$ (read -s password; echo $password; echo >&2) \
  | ssh remote sudo -S echo bar | tr bar foo
```

I'm sure there must be a good solution to this, as it doesn't seem an uncommon thing to want to do.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` for `ssh` in the first place?

Comment: How else do you suggest I execute code as root on a remote server that does not allow root login (i.e. that has `PermitRootLogin no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), @jww?  Maybe there is a better solution, but I can't immediately think of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with is to use `sudo -S` and disable local echo so the password isn't shown as you type it:

```
$ { stty -echo; ssh remote sudo -S echo hello; stty echo; echo 1>&2; }
[sudo] password for user:
hello
```

This leaves sudo in charge of the password prompting, so it works properly if the user types the password wrong.

I don't think any solution using `ssh -t` can ever work properly, since it combines stderr and stdout.

Comment: There's a missing semicolon after `1>&2`.

Comment: If you want to get the newline echoed in the right place, you want to do that echo before echoing the remote content:  i.e. `{ stty -echo; ssh remote sudo -S "echo 1>&2; echo bar"; stty echo; } | tr bar foo`

Comment: Fixed missing semicolon. Thanks!

Comment: That's a useful example for when you want the output on the terminal. If you're redirecting the output to a file or a command which doesn't give any output then it doesn't matter where the newline appears and you can use my slightly simpler version (no quoting needed).